MongooseError: Operation `posts.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
I am using MongoDB Atlas, while creating a post first time I am encountring with this  MongooseError: Operation posts.insertOne() buffering timed out after 10000ms at Timeout. (D:\React\linkedin-clone\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
If I send request from Insomnia/Postman, a post created successfully first time but it is errroring if I send request from my frontend. Once the post is created successfully any subsequest request from frontend is als successful.
Below is my db.ts file and route.ts
Can someone please tell what is wrong!
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL;

if (!connectionString) {
  throw new Error("Please provide a valid connection string.");
}

const connectDB = async () => {
  if (mongoose.connection?.readyState === 1) {
    console.log("Already conneced to MongoDB.......");
    return;
  }

  try {
    console.log("Connecting to MongoDB.......");
    await mongoose.connect(connectionString, {
      serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 20000, // Adjust as needed
    });
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error(`Failed to connect to MongoDB: ${error.message}`);
  }
};

export default connectDB;

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  await connectDB();
  // auth.protect();
  console.log("new post>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

  try {
    const { user, postText, imageUrl }: AddPostRequestBody =
      await request.json();
    const newPost: IPostBase = {
      user,
      postText,
      ...(imageUrl && { imageUrl }),
    };

    const post = await Post.create(newPost);
    console.log("inside post create????????????????????");
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Post created successfully", post });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("inside error block....");
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: "An error occurred while adding a new post." },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}


Mongoose connects lazily.  Try adding a command like ping inside the connectDB function to make sure the connection is fully open and usable before it returns.

Thank you, the thing that worked for me is calling connectDB() in my CreatePostAction.ts  instead of calling it inside the route.ts file.
